# Easy way to rescale vectors in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I'm an happy user of the `with vectors` options in Gnuplot. However, in most case, the vectors need to be rescaled to make a nice figure.

Currently, I am doing this by

```
plot "data" using 1:2:($3*scale):($4*scale) with vectors
```

Ideally, I would just like to skip `using` and writing the scale for vector-length manually once, such that I could use

```
plot "data" with vectors scale 0.1
```

Maybe there is an auto-scaling option that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no shortcut for that as far as I know.  The best you'll probably do is to use a macro:

```
set macros
with_vectors = "using 1:2:($3*scale):($4*scale) w vectors"
scale = 0.1
plot "data" @with_vectors
scale = 0.2
plot "data" @with_vectors
```

Comment: Can these macros be set when gnuplot is loaded?

Comment: You can put it in your `.gnuplot` file.  That works for interactive scripts -- I'm not sure if it works for "batch" scripts though ... Looking at the docs (`help startup`), it seems to imply that it gets loaded either way